# Interdependent Column JavaFx TableView

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have an issue that Column X having Combobox will be populated on every record. the combobox column is dependent on other column's data. I am using ObservableList of ObservableMap to populate TableView.

Please do help me how can we achieve that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some of the code where you have your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already solved the problem by workout on TableCell